# FindElementsInHostCoordinates affected by parent?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8

I am facing following problem. I try to implement a drag and drop between two grids and to find out where the Element I want to drop is moved I use VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates. But the grid which my Element is child of is always returned as Element at my touch-point. Here is the Code. Thanks for help.

```
    private void Start_Drag(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ManipulationContainer = LayoutRoot;
        Anchor.X = e.ManipulationOrigin.X;
        Anchor.Y = e.ManipulationOrigin.Y;

        (sender as UIElement).RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();

        (sender as FrameworkElement).Parent.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 50);
    }

    private void Do_Drag(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        var FinalPoint = new Point(e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.X + Anchor.X, e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.Y + Anchor.Y + 28);
        Debug.WriteLine("cumulative_drag ({0},{1})", FinalPoint.X, FinalPoint.Y);

        var Elements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(FinalPoint, LayoutRoot);
        Debug.WriteLine("({0},{1})", Elements.Contains(SourceGrid), Elements.Contains(CoursesGrid));

        ((sender as UIElement).RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).X = e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.X;
        ((sender as UIElement).RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).Y = e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.Y;
    }

    private void End_Drag(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var FinalPoint = new Point(e.TotalManipulation.Translation.X + Anchor.X, e.TotalManipulation.Translation.Y + Anchor.Y + 42);
        Debug.WriteLine("end_drag ({0},{1})", FinalPoint.X, FinalPoint.Y);
        var Elements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(FinalPoint, this);
        var IsOverSource = Elements.Contains(SourceGrid);
        var IsOverCourses = Elements.Contains(CoursesGrid);
        (sender as UIElement).RenderTransform = null;

        //push to background
        (sender as FrameworkElement).Parent.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, -50);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this link [Drag and drop from list to canvas on windows phone with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859855/drag-and-drop-from-list-to-canvas-on-windows-phone-with-mvvm)

Basicly you can use transform instead. Such that you can convert the point of your element to a position on the two different grids, and then check position, if its negative or too big you can use logik to define where it is.